# How to do symbolic or hard linking in Chef

Tags: chef-infra

Have two recipes "sshkey_generation" and "dbaas_json_creation" .

sshkey_generation has something like :

#

```
file '/tmp/keys/ssh_public.pub' do
content public_key
end
```

#

Where we are creating public key file inside directory and the same is working fine .

recipe "dbaas_json_creation" has something like :

```
 vmPublicKeyText = File.read("/scratch/keys/ssh_public.pub")
 puts vmPublicKeyText
```

Now while executing both recipes through runlist , then get error like :

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /scratch/keys/ssh_public.pub
```

with runlist second recipe is executing first and looking fro directory which depends on first recipe. Need to confirm on how to do symbolic or hard linking , As i tried below code inside "dbaas_json_creation" but still same issue.

```
 link "/scratch/json/fcubs-dbcs-create.json" do
 to "/scratch/keys/ssh_public.pub"
 link_type :hard
 end
```

Any suggestions ???

Comment: Could you please share your chef run log with us too?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a compile vs converge problem. See https://coderanger.net/two-pass for details.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can read here, you are creating the file under `/tmp` directory and later you try to access `/scratch` directory.

Then you are trying to link a non-existent directory (/scratch).

Try modifying on the first recipe `/tmp/keys/ssh_public.pub` to `/scratch/keys/ssh_public.pub` or vice-versa.

Comment: This is not related.

Comment: Navarro , That's by mistake I have given wrong directories , I am actually reading from the same directory where i am creating "ssh_public.pub"